# How to derive (the dimensionless coefficient in front of) the moment of inertia for common shapes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, moment-of-inertia

Is there a way to derive (the dimensionless coefficient in front of) the [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) for common shapes? I assume it has to do with the density of the shape, but I'm having trouble seeing it.

For example the moment of inertia for a cylinder is $I = \frac12 M R^2$ while the moment of inertia for a hoop is $I = M R^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by `coefficient' of moment of inertia? I've never encountered `coefficient` in this context. Normally one refers to `moment of inertia.`  Any good university physics or engineering mechanics book will outline the procedure.

Comment: my apologies for vagueness. I have edited to include explanation

Comment: The [Wikipedia entry for *moment of inertia* is quite detailed in the calculations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia).

Comment: @KyleKanos - I would say it is more than "quite detailed"; one can easily drown in the details given there. But I do agree that it is a good suggestion to read the article and 'come back if you have any questions after that'.

Comment: @Floris, you're wrong; it's not "more than "quite detailed"". See, for example, the definition of "quite" at: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quite

Comment: @hft - OK, my point was that it might be "too" detailed. I like to think of "quite" as "a lot, in a good way".

Comment: moment of inertia is defined and derived as an integral, fomr of which you can fetch on wiki

Comment: Yes, it would be just fair to accept the best answer. By the way, Charles' reply was already clear when you accepted Floris' answer, which is an ordinary run-of-the-mill explanation.

Comment: For info only: A concept that is kind of "dual" to what you're groping for is the *radius of gyration*: the radius a thin ring of concentrated mass centered on a given axis would need to be to have the same MOI about that axis as the body in question.

Comment: I second the above comment. The key concept here is the _radius of gyration_ which simplifies complex shapes down to a rotating ring of concentrated mass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, the moment of inertia depends on "how much of the mass is how far away from the axis of rotation". If the radial mass distribution is $m(r)$ then the moment of inertia is given by

$$I=\int m(r) r^2 dr$$

In the case of a hoop, all the material is the same distance $R$ away. But if you take a solid disk, you can think of this disk as being made up of a series of concentric hoops - each hoop bigger, and heavier, than the previous one.

This leads to a simple integral. If we consider a disk of mass M and radius R, then the mass per unit area is $\rho = \frac{M}{\pi R^2}$. Imagine we cut a hoop of radius $r$, thickness $dr$ from this disk. It would have area $2\pi r \ dr$. Its mass would be $2\pi r\ dr\ \rho$, and its moment of inertia $2 \pi r\ dr\ \rho\ r^2 = 2 \pi r\ dr \frac{M}{\pi R^2} r^2 = 2 \frac{M}{R^2} r^3 dr$

Summing the total moment of inertia of all these hoops, we get

$$I = \int_0^R 2 \frac{M}{R^2} r^3 dr = \frac12 M R^2$$

A similar method can be used for any other shape - if you break it up into little segments that have their mass at the same distance from the center of rotation, then the moment of inertia of that segment is easily determined; and then you just add all contributions to give you the total moment of inertia.

Comment: I think that you should include the general formula in your answer.